# Clarification about Events and Delegates in C#

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I am learner in C# programming language.I am not able to comprehend the base idea about `Events and Delegates`. I have viewed numerous tutorials about `Events and Delegates` however I am still confused about their concept.I additionally don't understand the base point of utilizing events.I know somewhat about `Delegates` that delegates are similar to function pointers we can call any function utilizing `Delegate` with same parameters and return type yet why events are used.Can somebody likewise clarify a situation in which it is important to utilize an Event on the grounds that all is well if I don't utilize `Events` also please explain Is `EventHandler` a type or a class? in the code below

```
public static event EventHandler myevent;
```

Thank You.

Comment: Have you read about the [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8627sbea.aspx) keyword and [how to work with events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/awbftdfh.aspx)?

Comment: If a class/instance exposes an event, it tells the world: "hey, maybe at some point(s) in my life time something might happen that might interested some of you. If you are indeed interested in knowing about it, register here!" Now other objects can say "well, I am interested in knowing if that something does happen. So I will register/subscribe to that event by giving you a method (delegate) I'd like you to run for me if that something does indeed happen."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get delegates than you can think of an event of just being a collection/list of those delegates you will call on demand (if you raise the event) - it's nothing more.

It's a convenient form of letting information flow out of your objects when you don't know (or don't want to know) who might be interested in those informations.

For the second part of your question: `EventHandler` is just a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) that gives a common form (the sender of the event and the information as `EventArgs`)

Answer (score 0):

Events raise up a flag with something happens, common ones are when you click on a button, it raises an event telling others that 'something' happened.  An event handler is there to do something when that event is is raised.

So when you click a button you may want to do something, you set a handler to activate when the button is clicked.  You can also have multiple event handlers attached to a specific event, each one doing something different.

The event keyword just a way to create your own 'button clicks' or 'on selection changed' events and the EventHandler lets you catch them and do stuff after that.

Answer (score 0):

`EventHandler` is a delegate, is a delegate, is a delegate... a function pattern, if you will.

The whole `Event` and `Delegate` system is more of a design pattern, which was build into the language. Once you get used to it and start defining your own `Delegates` and `EventArgs` you will find it to be pretty convenient.
Also their usage is common sense, so you need less documentation, if you want to share your libraries.